# How Can I make an R for loop for summations?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Hello I'm really new to R and having trouble figuring this out, I have to make a summation and compute for different values of n

[Here is the summation I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZGoW.png)

I have the following code

x=0:10

k=x

sum(1(k+1)^2)

which gives me the answer for the first value of N, however, do I just repeat it for all different values of N, or can I make a for loop that will go from 0:10 -> 0:20 -> 0:50 -> 0:100
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi hunter12756,

you can use for loops, however, r is the language that encourages you to solve problems differently. Please, read about vectors and what data types are used in r, before trying to go further with your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of sequences and then use `sapply` :

```
x= list(0:10, 0:20, 0:50, 0:100)

result <- sapply(x, function(k) sum(1/(k+1)^2))
result
#[1] 1.558 1.598 1.626 1.635
```

With a `for` loop :

```
result <- numeric(length(x))
for(i in seq_along(x)) {
  result[i] <- sum(1/(x[[i]]+1)^2)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do thank you :D